# Codeigniter send email message link not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am try to send confirmation registration email to user by using Codeigniter. I need to send a verify link but it has problem with dot sign before protocol such as **.com**. And I tried to delete dot sign " **.** " before **com** it works correctly. Please see my code bellow:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->from('info@mymail.com');
$this->email->subject('Mail Confirm');
$message = "<p>Thanks for registration and you have successfuly register.</p>";
$message .= "<p>Please click link here to confirm your registration.</p>";
                //Here is my problem
$message .= "<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/job_pages/active?code=".$code."' >test</a>";

$this->email->message($message);
```

Comment: What problem ? What does the log says ? What is the output of `email->print_debugger()` when it fails ? See [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your link been blocked by mail server security, from your destination email. I have seen your code. I think there are nothing wrong. Do you have tried to embed a verified web like Facebook, or Twitter to check your code.

```
    <?php
    $message .= "<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/job_pages active?code=".$code."'>
    test</a>";
    //just to check change it to
    $message .="<a href='https://www.facebook.com'>test</a>";
    ?>
```

you would like to create link alias at tiny.cc. That easy just type your web URL, then get your web alias. Maybe you must configure your rout file on your ci configuration, to customize the effect. I have tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem in the code you've included, can you include more of your code?

I assume you **must** have put:

```
$this->email->send(); 
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

after your `$this->email->message($message);` line if you said it was working before?